# OnPause state Force to Kill the Android App

Tags: android, exception

I am new to Android development.I have created a small app and i have start the app in my device it's working good.After some state i hit the "home" button so the Activity should go to the onPause() state then i  used some other application.My issue is It keeps the activity in the background nearly 45 minutes after it force to move onStop() method and close the Android App.When i again go to the home and click the icon instead of calling restart() method it's calling onCreate() method.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `onPause()` you can call `Activity_name.this.finish()`

You may want to learn a little more about [Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)